# how to show specific approval dashboard to some users and not all approval types in odoo 16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I want to show the few approval types to the one user and few to the other is it possible in odoo16 through coding or some kind of setting?

For example in the picture i don't want to show the cross approval types to user A and want to show the all to the user B.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it By using Groups and Record Rules.

Comment: how what kind of rule will be apply on it ?

Comment: You can create 2 boolean like is_a or is_b and add domain like is_a = True for the record rule of group A and similar for group B